# Problem with creating consul cluster using ansible

Tags: ansible, vagrant, microservices, vagrantfile, consul

I'm trying to create a Consul cluster using Ansible and i'm using this example https://github.com/brianshumate/ansible-consul .i'm using the vagrant file to up 3 Ubuntu machines

the problem is that the task `Install unzip package` seem to always fail,and it gives this error message:

```
fatal: [consul1.consul -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not detect which package manager to use. Try gathering facts or setting the \"use\" option."}
```

Ansible seem unable to recognize the package manager,even though `ansible localhost -m setup | grep mgr` shows that the variable `ansible_pkg_mgr` has the value `apt`

i'm not sure what could be the source of the problem.i tried upping 3 debian machines and i still have the same problem.

UPDATE:
here's the task file for consul

```
---
# File: install.yml - package installation tasks for Consul

- name: Install OS packages
  package:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ consul_os_packages }}"
  tags: installation

- name: Read package checksum file
  local_action:
    module: stat
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul_{{ consul_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  register: consul_checksum
  tags: installation

- name: Download package checksum file
  local_action:
    module: get_url
    url: "{{ consul_checksum_file_url }}"
    dest: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul_{{ consul_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  tags: installation
  when: not consul_checksum.stat.exists | bool

- name: Read package checksum
  local_action:
    module: shell
      grep "{{ consul_pkg }}" "{{ role_path }}/files/consul_{{ consul_version }}_SHA256SUMS" | awk '{print $1}'
  become: no
  run_once: true
  register: consul_sha256
  tags: installation

- name: Check Consul package file
  local_action:
    module: stat
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ consul_pkg }}"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  register: consul_package
  tags: installation

- name: Download Consul package
  local_action:
    module: get_url
    url: "{{ consul_zip_url }}"
    dest: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ consul_pkg }}"
    checksum: "sha256:{{ consul_sha256.stdout }}"
    timeout: "42"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  tags: installation
  when: not consul_package.stat.exists | bool

- name: Update alpine package manager (apk)
  local_action:
    module: apk
    update_cache: yes
  run_once: true
  when: lookup('file','/etc/alpine-release')

- name: Install unzip package
  local_action:
    module: package
    name: unzip
    state: present
  run_once: true
  when:
    - consul_install_dependencies | bool

- name: Unarchive Consul package
  local_action:
    module: unarchive
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ consul_pkg }}"
    dest: "{{ role_path }}/files/"
    creates: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  tags: installation

- name: Install Consul
  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul"
    dest: "{{ consul_bin_path }}/consul"
    owner: "{{ consul_user }}"
    group: "{{ consul_group }}"
    mode: 0755
  tags: installation

- name: Daemon reload systemd in case the binaries upgraded
  command: systemctl daemon-reload
  become: yes
  notify: restart consul
  when:
    - ansible_service_mgr == "systemd"
    - consul_install_upgrade

- name: Cleanup
  local_action: file path="{{ item }}" state="absent"
  become: no
  with_fileglob: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul"
  run_once: true
  tags: installation
```

Comment: You're going to have to post output at higher verbosity and/or a link to the actual task yaml, rather than having us _guess_ which file in that repo is trying to do what you said. Also, be aware that `ansible localhost` is not the same as running ansible against the vagrant inventory file, as there are many more things that can go wrong when interacting with a system remotely

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel it's done in the edit above,and sorry for that,i thought it's obvious to find. actually i tried the same example on a colleague's computer who runs Ubuntu as a main OS (i use Debian),and the execution crashed at the task "Update alpine package manager". maybe you can list the most  obvious causes of this kind of errors ? because for me it looks more like an environment issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Alpine package Manager,somehow it seem to cause an error with Ubuntu,so all what i did is use Apt instead of Apk.

here's the new version of the task file

```
---
# File: install.yml - package installation tasks for Consul

- name: Install OS packages
  package:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ consul_os_packages }}"
  tags: installation

- name: Read package checksum file
  local_action:
    module: stat
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul_{{ consul_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  register: consul_checksum
  tags: installation

- name: Download package checksum file
  local_action:
    module: get_url
    url: "{{ consul_checksum_file_url }}"
    dest: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul_{{ consul_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  tags: installation
  when: not consul_checksum.stat.exists | bool

- name: Read package checksum
  local_action:
    module: shell
      grep "{{ consul_pkg }}" "{{ role_path }}/files/consul_{{ consul_version }}_SHA256SUMS" | awk '{print $1}'
  become: no
  run_once: true
  register: consul_sha256
  tags: installation

- name: Check Consul package file
  local_action:
    module: stat
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ consul_pkg }}"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  register: consul_package
  tags: installation

- name: Download Consul package
  local_action:
    module: get_url
    url: "{{ consul_zip_url }}"
    dest: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ consul_pkg }}"
    checksum: "sha256:{{ consul_sha256.stdout }}"
    timeout: "42"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  tags: installation
  when: not consul_package.stat.exists | bool

- name: Install unzip package
  apt:
    name: unzip
    state: present
  run_once: true
  when:
    - consul_install_dependencies | bool

- name: Unarchive Consul package
  local_action:
    module: unarchive
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ consul_pkg }}"
    dest: "{{ role_path }}/files/"
    creates: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul"
  become: no
  run_once: true
  tags: installation

- name: Install Consul
  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul"
    dest: "{{ consul_bin_path }}/consul"
    owner: "{{ consul_user }}"
    group: "{{ consul_group }}"
    mode: 0755
  tags: installation

- name: Daemon reload systemd in case the binaries upgraded
  command: systemctl daemon-reload
  become: yes
  notify: restart consul
  when:
    - ansible_service_mgr == "systemd"
    - consul_install_upgrade

- name: Cleanup
  local_action: file path="{{ item }}" state="absent"
  become: no
  with_fileglob: "{{ role_path }}/files/consul"
  run_once: true
  tags: installation
```